# Create File Templates in IntelliJ Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How do I create file templates in an IntelliJ plugin?

Main purpose is the concurrent usage of multiple plugins for batch processing in an project wizard.

Is there any simple example or a small example project where I can look how to do this stuff? Unfortunatelly almost any link beloning this topic is broken in the Jetbrains forums.

I already found [Idea-Android](https://github.com/bennythomps/idea-android) but I'm not really sure how they create the (for example) Manifest.xml file.